# Javascript получить полный путь к сохраненному файлу

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function downloadURL(i,url) {
  if (\$idown[i]) {
   $idown.attr('src',url);
  } else {
   $idown = $('<iframe>', { id:'idown[i]', src:url }).hide().appendTo('body');
  }
}
```

Загружаю несколько файлов, нужно после загрузки получить полный путь к скаченному файлу.
Далее выгружаю на другой сервер.

Comment: путь вы не можете определить по причине недоступности

Comment: Это должен вернуть сервер, ибо он сохранил куда-то полученное. А если вопрос о получении пути на устройстве клиента - забудьте, это накрепко запрещено правилами безопасности, да и не нужно это в подавляемом количестве случаев.